How can I create a BitLocker volume on Windows 10 that is backward-compatible with Windows 8.1 or earlier?
On Windows 10, how can I turn on BitLocker on a volume such that Windows 8.1 or earlier will be able to read/write to it?

You would have to encrypt the drive with Windows 8.1. Windows 11 won’t allow you to use the weaker cipher but it still supports it for a drive already encrypted

@Ramhound I'm asking about Windows 10 not 11... is it the same story there? Also, is the cipher itself actually weaker, or is there a different incompatibility?

The BitLocker cipher changes happened with Windows 10.
